# Azure DevOps Query on State Change Date - Results Don't Include Custom WIT

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I have custom Work Item Types setup with 'normal' states (first image).

When I query (second image) on *State = Resolved* and *State Change Date > @Today - 7*, Work Items with the Custom types are not found despite having the Resolved state assigned within the last week.

What do I need to do to make such a query work?

[image: States]

[image]

Comment: It works fine on my side with Azure DevOps, I suppose it should be also work for TFS. Could you confirm that your custom work item was created 7 days ago? Have you tried set the state change date <= @Today-7?

Comment: I'm in Azure DevOps too (not TFS).  We have numerous work items are created daily so yes, there are work items created between today and 7 days ago.  Using <= @ Today-7 also returns no results.

Comment: The query will return work items that use a 'stock' type.  The only work items it doesn't return are the ones we created in our customized process template. So my assumption is that there is some setup in the process template that is preventing the query logic from working.

Answer (score 0):

Found that this is a confirmed bug
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/373206/state-changed-date-not-available-on-our-custom-wit.html